# Is there a way to clear sharp edges using bmesh in python?

Tags: python, bmesh

I'm trying to speed up an addon that had to toggle into *Edit Mode* for sometimes thousands of object by staying at the object level using bmesh instead of `object.editmode_toggle()`.

Is there any operation to clear sharp edges without having to enter *Edit Mode* for each object?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41351/is-there-a-way-to-select-edges-marked-as-sharp-via-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set [`use_edge_sharp`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.MeshEdge.html?highlight=use_edge_sharp#bpy.types.MeshEdge.use_edge_sharp) flag per edge on [MeshData.edges](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Mesh.html?highlight=edges#bpy.types.Mesh.edges) in *Object Mode*:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object

# Clear sharp state for all edges
for edge in obj.data.edges:
    edge.use_edge_sharp = False
```

---

If there is no way around *Bmesh* for whatever reason, you can set the [`smooth`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.types.html?highlight=smooth#bmesh.types.BMEdge.smooth) state of all edges to `True` in *Edit Mode*:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

# Clear sharp state for all edges 
for edge in bm.edges:
    edge.smooth = True

# Update the mesh
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, False, False)
```

Related: [Is there a way to select edges marked as sharp via python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41352/31447)

Comment: While this is not the requested bmesh solution, this should be faster due to not requiring the bmesh conversion. If your workflow has bmesh conversion anyway, you can use this before or after the bmesh part, not during.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely right, should be indeed way faster without the conversion... Thanks @kheetor

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to experiment with different methods and see which combination of approaches works the fastest. The main method that I could only get with bmesh or toggling into edit mode was limited dissolve. I think there are other ways to do this as well, since I think it is mostly removing/merging colinear edges and coplanar faces.