# bmesh smooth property isn't set

Tags: python, bmesh, smooth

I want to select all sharp edges using a script. I tried something like what's suggested here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41352/177165 which uses a bmesh edge's `smooth` property. This doesn't seem to work.

In the example below, I try selecting all the not-`smooth` edges of a cube, and I get an empty list. For the first edge in the list, I print some debug info to verify - it's not marked smooth, although its face_angle is about 90 degrees.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
# delete everything
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    obj.select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

# make the box
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
box = bpy.context.active_object

# find all sharp edges
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
me = box.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
sharp_edges = [e for e in bm.edges if not e.smooth]
print(f"sharp edges: {sharp_edges}")

# debug info for edge 0
bm.edges.ensure_lookup_table()
print(f"edge 0 smooth: {bm.edges[0].smooth}")
import numpy as np
from math import degrees
theta = degrees(bm.edges[0].calc_face_angle_signed())
print(f"edge 0 face angle: {theta}")
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

the output I get is:

```
sharp edges: []
edge 0 smooth: True
edge 0 face angle: 89.999995674289
```

Is my understanding of the `smooth` property wrong? Or does `bmesh` not set the property by default?